# Systemd logs only 3 lines of errors

Tags: linux, systemd, logs, systemd-journald

I have an error when running command

```
assert.js:81
  throw new assert.AssertionError({
  ^
AssertionError: APP_API env var not set
    at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/offero-html-server/src/routes/offer.js:13:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
```

Which in `journalctl -u my-service` gets the following output

```
44:44 offero-web systemd[1]: my-service.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Jun 29 11:44:44 user-web systemd[1]: Stopped offero-html-server.service.
Jun 29 11:44:44 user-web systemd[1]: Started offero-html-server.service.
Jun 29 11:44:45 user-web my-service[17748]: assert.js:81
Jun 29 11:44:45 user-web my-service[17748]:   throw new assert.AssertionError({
Jun 29 11:44:45 user-web my-service[17748]:   ^
Jun 29 11:44:45 user-web systemd[1]: my-service.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jun 29 11:44:45 user-web systemd[1]: my-service.service: Unit entered f
```

How can I see untruncated output ?

Answer (score 0):

`journalctl --no-page` does this but it does not work for individual units obviously.